# JMeter script from version 2 takes many hours to open in version 5

Tags: jmeter

I want to switch a script from version 2 to version 5 of JMeter. (Strangely) I could not find instructions how to convert scripts via web search. One of my guesses is that scripts does not require conversion, old scripts can be opened in newer versions.

In case of that particular script it looks kind of correct. It opens, when opened it runs almost fine. The issue is that it takes sereral hours to open it in ver 5 whereas in original ver 2 it takes couple of minutes. I tried to save opened script in ver 5 to new file. Version 2 gives errors when it's trying to open that new file, so looks like some conversion takes place. However, that new file still takes hours to open again in version 5. When I open similar short scripts made in ver 2 and ver 5 they look about the same xml files.

How to make script made in ver 2 to open quickly in ver 5? What could be of issue here?

EDIT: looks like the problem is not in particular script. A script created from scratch in ver 5 now takes like an hour to save (it's about 1mb file), I closed apps to free memory before starting ver 5 to have clean result. Ver 2 saved 10mb file in sereral seconds. Could it be java version, some settings?

Comment: Try to set up some more verbose logging to JMeter (https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging). Probably DEBUG or TRACE level messages will give you a clue.

Comment: Your jmx seems rather large, although not of a size I would expect problems. Do you include a lot of scripting code for instance, references to external (script) files that have problems resolving? Jmeter tends to behave sluggish with larger files, but 'hours'? I just created a 40MB file by repeatedly adding a preprocessor with code, but it still loaded within 10s...

Comment: Alexei, could you share your jmx file? (without any private information of course).
>Could it be java version, some settings
What is your java version and system ?

Comment: @Ray Oei,@Vadim Yangunaev. The "testing" script is made of one time controller having  2 one time controllers + JDBC sampler (just made in GUI no info added) copy-pasted "recursively" to form a binary tree - is it clear enough what was done? - I'm not sure it's ok at my job to upload the file. The 'depth' that already resulted in long copy-paste/save time and 700Kb file is 10.

Comment: @Ray Oei,@Vadim Yangunaev. Windows and java version gives 1.8